# Can't use Poco TCPServer and TCPServerConnectionFactory

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, poco-libraries

I'm using a TCPServer inside an activity.
For simplify my design I make my activity ihnerit from TCPServerConnectionFactory.
With that, my activity implement CreateConnection() method.

To create my TCPServer I make :

```
Poco::Net::TCPServer(this, serverSocket);
```

Unfortunately, when my TCPServer is destroyed, it also destroy (this) that I have given in parameter. So it call dtor of my activity, that's really annoying.

Looking deeply in the Poco code and I see that TCPServer create a Poco::shared_Ptr of (this) and when this Shared_Ptr is destroyed, it delete the content of the shared_ptr.

How I can pass (this) to TCPServer without be destroyed at the end of the life of TCPServer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the connection factory allocated on the heap to the TCPServer. For an example, see [TimeServer](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/TimeServer/src/TimeServer.cpp) example:

```
class TimeServerConnection: public TCPServerConnection
{
  //...
};

// ...

class TimeServerConnectionFactory: public TCPServerConnectionFactory
{
  // ...
  TCPServerConnection* createConnection(const StreamSocket& socket)
  {
    return new TimeServerConnection(socket, _format);
  }
  // ...
};

// set-up a server socket
ServerSocket svs(port);
// retain the handle to shared ptr for later use
TCPServerConnectionFactory::Ptr pTSCF = new TimeServerConnectionFactory(format);
// set-up a TCPServer instance
TCPServer srv(pTSCF, svs);
```

Comment: Yes I know that I can do that with a new TSC() but I would like to give a persistant object which will not be destroyed automatically at the end of the life of the TCPServer

Comment: You can keep the shared pointer so it will not be destroyed in TCPServer because you will have the last ref count. I have updated the code in the answer above.

Comment: Ok I can do that but is there a possibility to create a shared ptr of this ?

Comment: TCPServerConnectionFactory::Ptr is Poco::SharedPtr, see  https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/TCPServerConnectionFactory.h#L48

Comment: Yes I know but if I would to use first idea I would to provide this to TCP server as this is TCPServerConnectionFactory. If think I can't do Poco::Net::TCPServer(TCPServerConnectionFactory::Ptr(this), serverSocket);

Comment: You can't do that because a new reference count with value of 1 will be created for the temporary SharedPtr and when temporary is destructed, this will be deleted. Poco::AutoPtr provides a solution to that, but it does not apply here. I could be missing something, but I'm not quite sure whether inheriting from the factory indeed simplifies the design.

Comment: It prevent me to create two different class and provide a lot of object from the server to the factory